# what does E[$c^x$] mean in probability

Tags: probability, expectation

Hello I'm self studying probability this summer and I would like your help to clarify me on this question.

Let x be such that $P(X=1)=p=1-P(X=-1)$.

Find $c≠1$ such that $E[c^x]=1$

Can anyone tell me what does $E[c^x]$ mean in probability?

I know that $E[x]$ is the expected value and it's a number but  $E[c^x]$
???

Comment: $$\begin{gathered}
  E\left[ {g\left( X \right)} \right] = \sum\limits_x {g\left( x \right)P\left( {X = x} \right)}  \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow E\left( {{c^X}} \right) = \sum\limits_x {{c^x}P\left( {X = x} \right)}  = {c^1}P\left( {X = 1} \right) + {c^{ - 1}}P\left( {X =  - 1} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
In general, for any function $f(x)$, we have 
$$
E[f(x)]=\sum_{i}f(i)P(x=i).
$$
END EDIT

Expanding on the comment above, 
$$
E[c^x]=c^1P(x=1)+c^{-1}P(x=-1)=pc+\frac{1-p}{c}.
$$
Thus if we have $E[c^x]=1$, we want
$$
pc+\frac{1-p}{c}=1
$$
or 
$$
pc^2+(1-p)=c
$$
or 
$$
pc^2-c+(1-p)=0.
$$
The quadratic formula can now be used to solve for $c$ in terms of $p$.

Comment: thank you i have $C= (1-p)/p)$

Comment: That looks like it works (so long as $p\neq 0$)